# i++ keep on incrementing during page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

i++ keep on increasing whenever I reload the page.It should only increment when I trigger the button but I found out that during page reload it also increments.
I did the `!IsPostBack` but I still encounter the problem.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            cart_number();
        }
    }


    private static int i;
    private void cart_number()
    {
        lbl_cart_number.Text = i++.ToString();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cart_number();
    }
```

Comment: How do you "trigger the button"?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen when I click it.

Comment: Warning: that `static int i` is *shared* between *all* visitors to your site.

Comment: @HansKesting what should I use Instead?

Comment: @rainalasa a dictionary with the user name as the key and an integer as the value.

Comment: No, please no! @Gusdor Use the `Session` object instead! You don't want to have risky code that is shared across all users. What if you screw up and suddenly show the data of another user?

Comment: @PatrickHofman What if? I think your meant _when_ :D Good suggestion. Please accept my retraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reload a page, it means that it's not a `IsPostBack`. You should remove `cart_number();` from your `Page_Load`. The `Page_Load` will be triggered each time there is an interaction between the browser and the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `cart_number()` method call from your 'Page_Load'. No need to call that method on `Page_Load`. Any specific reason why you call from `Page_Load()`?

Comment: When I randomly reloaded my website I saw my lbl_cart_number incrementing so I thought I could stop it from increasing when I use !IsPostBack

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        cart_number("1");
    }
   }


private static int i;
private void cart_number(string flag)
{
    int lbl=0;
    lbl =int.Parse(lbl_cart_number.Text);
    if(flag!="1"){
    i=lbl;
    if(i>=0){
    lbl_cart_number.Text =( i+1).ToString();
     }
    }
    else
   {
     lbl_cart_number.Text ="0";
   }
  }
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    cart_number("2");
   }
```

Comment: Why should he try that?

Comment: To create a better answer (with a chance of upvotes), do not just dump code but explain *what* you changed and *why* you did that.